# Prepending fa-icon to <li>using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, font-awesome

Trying to prepend a stacked icon before any list item on my site. Rather than go through and add the `html`to every `<li>` I'm trying to do it using jQuery however it is not working! Any ideas where I'm going wrong?! Many thanks in advance. 
Heres my code:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("li").prepend("<span class='fa-stack fa-lg'><i class='fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x'></i><i class='fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x'></i></span>");
   });
</script>
```

Comment: show us the html too

Comment: its working http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/166/

Comment: @AnoopJoshi the `html` is simply any time `<li>` is used.
It does work when you insert text between the `html` tags however it doesnt work as planned in that the FontAwesome icon does not show

Comment: Include the Fontawesome.css file into you html head and you're good to go: http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/167/
Guide: https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/

Comment: @AnoopJoshi, put it as an answer

Comment: Does anyone have the answer? @Capricorn thanks but I'm very familiar with how to use FontAwesome, have been for a long time, please read my question again.

Comment: The fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/169/) does exactly what you described in your question. If it does not work in your code, compare it with the fiddle-solution or please provide further details and code examples about what you're aiming for.